# Quickfix/J: message logs archiving and clean up

Tags: java, logging, quickfixj

When running a Java application with QuickFix/J library, is it possible to configure the Quickfix/J logs to be archived every midnight (or when we reach a certain size)? and to delete the logs when the max number of logs reaches x log files?

Similar behavior as logback for Java spring boot logs for example...

Comment: This could only be configured via the log framework, log4j for example

Comment: Maybe this helps:  https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/discussions/558